# Is it Neccesary to delete the partitions before reinstalling Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation

I am having Problems using Gparted to turn off swap on the swap drive to move though [this re installation guide](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reinstallation)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  What exactly is your problem?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: I right click linux-swap in GParted and then click swapoff and get this error
(-) Could not deactivate swap
swapoff:dev/sda5: swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory

Comment: I would edit that into your question.

Comment: To get best advice here you need to [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/277695/edit) to give more details on why you need to reinstall, why the default installation process from CD failed, why you think you need to delete your partitions, and mostly why you think you need to repartition swap as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no need to partition a drive before we install or re-install Ubuntu in an uncomlicted default setting. The installer will take care of this for you.

When booting the live CD on a system which already has 12.10 installed you will see the following screen after choosing *"Intall Ubuntu"*:

[image]

This will let you choose to

- ***"Reinstall"*** with keeping your HOME and settings for your applications.
- ***"Erase and reinstall"*** with deleting everything.

Which option is best for you depends entirely on the reasons you have for reinstalling, and also on your machine's further setup, e.g. you may **not** want to choose *"Erase.."* in case you are dual-booting another OS.

In general the swap partition will be used by the new installation and unless we need to resize it there will be no need to delete it.